# Add new column from conditional logic in Octave

Tags: octave

Let's say I have this vector (or matrix)

```
 a = [1; 2; 3]
```

it is a 3x1

1

2

3

How would I add another column based off conditional logic?

Say I want the second column to be 1 or 0 depending on if the first column is>= 2

What vectorized code would conditionally create and concatenate to create this?

1  0

2  1

3  1

I know R better, and with data.table I can do something similar to

data[col1 >= 2, second col := 1, ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `[]` to implicitly horizontally concatenate the two

```
b = [a, a >= 2];            % Implicit horizontal concatenation
```

Or you can use `horzcat` or `cat` to accomplish the same thing

```
b = horzcat(a, a >= 2);     % Horizontal contatenation
b = cat(2, a, a >= 2);      % Concatenate along the second dimension
```